# How to select rows with a special condition in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and my question is : in a matrix, I generated random mark between 0 and 20. Each row corresponds to a student, and each column to a subject. I would calculate how much students have the average in each subject, but I don't know how to test if the mark in each column is greater than 10. I think, I have to use "apply" and one function, but I don't succeed ...

```
nb.etu <- 60
nb.mat <- 12
notes <- matrix(
data = runif (n = nb.mat*nb.etu, min = 0, max = 20),
  nrow = nb.etu,
  ncol = nb.mat)

sexe <- sample(c("F","M"),size=60,replace=TRUE)
matrice <- cbind(notes,sexe)

# Class average

moy.mat <- apply(notes,2,mean)

# Student average

moy.etu <- apply(notes,1,mean)

# Student average for each subject

mod.info <- notes[,1:5]
moy.info <- apply(mod.info,1,mean)

mod.bio <- notes[,6:12]
moy.bio <- apply(mod.bio,1,mean)
```

Comment: Try `notes > 10`. It's pretty simple testing a condition on a matrix. By design, it looks like a data frame while allowing for vector-style operations. From there you can use that output as a way to subset further

Comment: Not sure if you really need apply but if you want to stick with this approach you can do something like this: `gt_10 <- apply(mod.bio,2,function(x) x>10)`

Comment: I tried with that, but I get an array filled with Boolean (True & False). What I want to know is how I can calculate how many students have a grade higher than 10 in each column (subject). And with "notes> 10" I only get the boxes in the table that have a value greater than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'd like to evaluate if the **average** of each column is more than 10 or not.

Try this one.

```
test.passed <- ifelse(moy.mat > 10, "Passed", "Failed")
rbind(notes, test.passed)
```

## modified 1

Then try this one.

```
sum(apply(notes, 1, function(x) all(x > 10)))
```

What this does is...

1. calculate if a student passed the test for each student
2. take the sum of the students passed

Comment: I don't want to evaluate if the average of each column is more than 10 or not. I want to evaluate if each element of a row is more than 10. If all values of a row are greater or equal to 10, the student passed all his exams. And then, the aim is to know how many student passed all their exams with grade > = 10.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I didn't know you could put "all" in the function.